# SQL query not executing in php command line interface created by me

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a SQL command line interface for my own purpose and testing with the following code:
**input.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
      'DESC'command under dev...
      <form action="output.php" method="post">
            <textarea name="query"></textarea>
            <input type="submit">
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**output.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
<?php

$servername = "server_name"; //I do not wish to show my credentials
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$sql = $_POST["query"];
$result = $conn->query($sql);
  if ($result === TRUE) {
        if (substr($sql, 0, 6) == "SELECT") {
              //Initialize table
              echo "<table class=\"table\">";
              echo "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Username</th><th>Password</th><th>Email</th></tr>";
              // output data of each row
              while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                     echo "<tr><td>" . $row["id"]. "</td><td>" . $row["username"]. "</td><td>" . $row["password"]. "</td><td>" . $row["email"] . "</td></tr>";
              }
              echo "</table>";

                echo "<code>" . $result->num_rows . " rows selected</code>";

    } elseif (substr($sql, 0,11) == "INSERT INTO") {
        echo "Inserted. Command: $sql";
    } elseif (substr($sql, 0, 6) == "DELETE") {
          echo "Deleted. Command: $sql";
    } elseif (substr($sql, 0, 6) == "UPDATE") {
          echo "Updated. Command: $sql";
    } else {
          echo "Code under dev...\nSorry!";
    }
  } else {
        echo "ERROR: " . $conn->error;
  }

  echo "<br>";
?>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have checked the database credentials; they're all fine- no conn error.
I know this because I worked with a table with some data before.
Now, on entering a query, nothing happens except it leaves a message- 'ERROR: '.
Please inform me of any errors.

Comment: Change `$sql = $_POST["query"];` to this `$sql = '"' . $_POST["query"] . '"';` and try.

Comment: Why bother there are many tools ALREADY available to test a query

Comment: Returns this: `ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"SELECT * FROM Members"' at line 1
`

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks but I'm doing a bit of testing work of my own...

Comment: so... you run the query and the test it's type???
What about `DROP DATABASE...` ???

Comment: @JulioSoares yes... I'm working on that...

Answer (score 0):

The query() function only returns TRUE when called with a SQL-statement that doesn't affect rows. In all other cases it returns an object of the type mysqli_result().

That causes the `if ($result === TRUE)` to jump to `else` and display the error. In fact there was no error, as $result probably holds a result object.

Try to confirm this by adding `echo $result->num_rows;` to your `else` clause.

[mysqli::query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

See the [mysqli::result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) documentation for more information on how to process your query results.

Comment: Not sure what you are saying, but I tried what you asked and it returned `mysqli_result Object ( ) `.

Comment: @Imagifight you're right. I just corrected my answer. myqsli_query() returns a mysqli_result() object which holds the number of rows.

Comment: I did not create a table yet, so that would be 0. As I said, nothing is working here! :)

Comment: I'm helping you to debug your code. Your comment is not helping me to help you. Please examine $result. We already know it's not TRUE, but it's a `mysqli_result()` object. Examine the object. Echo your query. Then get back with what you found and just maybe we can solve it then.

Comment: Sorry. Did this: `echo print_r($result); echo $result->num_rows; var_dump($result); echo $sql;`  Returned this: `mysqli_result Object ( )  0 object(mysqli_result)#2 (0) { } SELECT * FROM Members`